# How do I make 2 side-by-side images auto-fit both width and height of my mobile screen?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make 2 images (equal sizes) fit on a screen side by side always i.e. if the screen width is the limiting factor they must each take 50% of the width, and if the height is the limiting factor, they must display at 100% of the screen height. The following works perfectly with my phone in portrait (the width fits), but when I flip to landscape, the width still fits perfectly but the images are longer than the height.

How would I get it to scale factoring in both width and height so both images are always side by side, and fully visible?

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <img class="img-responsive col-xs-6" src="..." alt="card1" />
      <img class="img-responsive col-xs-6" src="..." alt="card2" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom style sheet that includes the codes like below:

```css
@media screen and (min-height: 321px /* or max-height: 321px */) {
  .img-responsive {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem I don't think? (1) why the arbitrary 321px? This needs to work on all screen sizes
 (2) width of 100% will mean both images won't be side by side?
 (3) height of auto will mean things might go off the bottom of the screen?

Comment: 321px is just an example. I didn't get your need before. You can edit the code. max-height could be 100% and width could be 50%. That would solve your problem.

Comment: thanks - with max-height at 100% and width at 50%, it still goes off the bottom of my screen when i rotate my phone?

Comment: If I would know rest of the codes, I could help better. But, u can try "float: left" if the problem is something as I thought.